# Angular 7 Can't bind to <property> since it isn't a known property of <component> (from imported module)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a module that is importing another module to use a component declared within it. In the example below, `ModuleAComponentC` is trying to use `ModuleBComponentA`. It would seem that `ModuleA` would need to import `ModuleB` in order to use it and therefore, `ModuleB` would need to export `ModuleBComponentA`. Seems straightforward enough, but the following is not working for me.

I get the `Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'module-b-component-a'`

#### `src/a/moduleA.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common"

import { ModuleAComponentC } from './c.component'
import { ModuleAComponentD } from './d.component'

import { ModuleB } from './../b/b.module'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule, 
    ModuleB
  ],
  declarations: [
    ModuleAComponentC,
    ModuleAComponentD
  ]
})
export class ModuleA {}
```

#### `src/b/moduleB.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common"

import { ModuleBComponentA } from './a.component'
import { ModuleBServiceA } from './a.service'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ModuleBComponentA
  ],
  providers: [
    ModuleBServiceA
  ],
  exports: [
    ModuleBComponentA
  ]
})
export class ModuleB {}
```

#### `src/b/a.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'module-b-component-a'
})
export class ModuleBComponentA {

  @Input('@') name: string

}
```

#### `src/a/c.component.html`

```
<module-b-component-a name="{{ test }}"></module-b-component-a>
```

Comment: Try: `@Input('name') name: string` in `ModuleBComponentA`

Comment: Ha! That solved it. I've been banging my head on this one for too long.

Comment: Feel free to leave that as an actual answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: Haha. Thanks :)

Comment: I am not familiar with AngularJS. If you are looking for a better way, you can certainly use property binding: `<module-b-component-a [name]="test"></module-b-component-a>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The thing you missed was to specify `name` in `@Input()`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'module-b-component-a'
})
export class ModuleBComponentA {
  @Input('name') name: string; // <-- 'name' in place of '@'
}
```